# 1080p resolution is not detected by screen.bounds and reverts to 720p

Tags: c#, windows, flash, graphics

I have a machine (Intel NUC) running windows 8 with a 1920x1080 resolution.
Windows displays the screen correctly at the right resolution.
However, when I create a C#, VB or AS3 application all report that the screen bounds are 1280x720 and revert back to 720p.

Has anyone ever had this problem, because it's driving me nuts and just doesn't make sense (to me)?

Thanks a lot for any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Yes. I have this problem too.on my system,adobe air pixel size is 3/2! that means when my screen resolution is 1600x1200,I should set the app's resolution 1067x800 (2/3) to fit the screen.so when you have the same problem,the problem is from Adobe AIR.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction Hitman.
I'm not sure that this is the same problem, because it works perfectly fine on my other system.

Comment: and I forgot.some times detect resolution 2/3 of real resolution.

Comment: I did some more research and it turns out that this is not air specific. If I create a c# winforms application I have the same problem.